# i have a huge line as string , need to find a specifi word inside it and return the number after it

Tags: python, string

Consider this line as string:

```
'false, "retweet_count": 4, "favorite_count": 117,'
```

I need to get the number (4) that is after the retweet_count.

My code:

```
retweet_index = line.find('retweet_count')
retweet = line[retweet_index+16:retweet_index+20] # but this fails as the number is variable from 0 - 100,000
```

How do I find a string and get the number after it?

Comment: Look into RegEx (Regular Expressions), they will do the job for you

Comment: What format is that?

Comment: string.split(":")[1].split(",")[0].strip()
This works for this specific string and will work for the ones with the same string format

Comment: Are you getting the data from a Twitter API? That string looks like a json file (or at least part of it).  If so, use the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) to exact the data into a `dict`. Then you can access all the values very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
line = 'false, "retweet_count": 405, "favorite_count": 117,'
print(re.findall(r'retweet_count": (\d+)', line)[0])
#405

#If the number can contain comma also,
line = 'false, "retweet_count": 100,000, "favorite_count": 117,'
print(re.findall(r'retweet_count": ([,0-9]+)(?=,\s)', line)[0])
#100,000
```

Comment: but when i tried it on spyder it worked perfectly but it is not working on my jupyter notebook , the whole code is follow 

with open('tweet-json copy','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            retweet = re.findall(r'retweet_count": (\d+)', line)[0]
            twt_output.append({'id': int(id), 
                               'tweet_created': pd.to_datetime(created_at),
                               'retweet_count': retweet, 
                               'favourite': fav})

Answer (score 0):

I am no python python programmer so I would rather not write code but 
if the data is in same format every time then why don't you simply convert string into an array separating by ',' and then you have you entry in second index that you can then separate by colon (:) and there you have it your value you need to remove space from front and back

Answer (score 0):

You could use `retweet_count = "retweet_count":` for your starting index.

Then you can slice the string `remaining = line[line.find(retweet_count) + len(retweet_count):]`
so that remaining looks like `4, "favorite_count": 117,'`

Then you can find the next " character
`retweets = remaining[:remaining.find('"')].strip()`

```
def get_retweet_count(line):
    retweet_count = '"retweet_count":'
    remaining = line[line.find(retweet_count) + len(retweet_count):]
    num_retweets = remaining[:remaining.find('"')].strip()
    print(num_retweets)
```

Regex would make since here too as seen in Sagar's answer.

I could also suggest if this is going to be a lot of data, then you could read into a dataframe if the format is consistent